# How to use javascript/node.js to push commits from one github repo to another

Tags: javascript, node.js, github, github-api

Is there anyway for me to push the commits made to master from GitHub repo A to Github repo B? I am trying something with SimpleGit but that doesn't seem to work.

This is my code:

```
simpleGit.init().addRemote('origin', 'git@github.com:owner/githubA.git');

octokit.request(`GET /repos/{owner}/{repo}/hooks/{hook_id}/deliveries`, {
        owner: owner,
        repo: repo,
        hook_id: 123456789,
    }).then(response => {
        octokit.request(`GET /repos/{owner}/{repo}/hooks/{hook_id}/deliveries/{delivery_id}`, {
            owner: owner,
            repo: repo,
            hook_id: 123456789,
            delivery_id: response.data[0].id
        }).then(response => {
            console.log(response.data.request['payload'].ref);
            if (response.data.request['payload'].ref == 'refs/heads/master') {
                console.log(response.data.request['payload'].commits);
                simpleGit.push('origin', 'master')
                    .then((success) => {
                        console.log(success);
                    }, (failed) => {
                        console.log('failed');
                    });
            }
        });
    });
```

I want to push whatever is in Github A to Github B using javascript/node.js packages. I mean once the push takes place in Github A, I want a remote push to happen to Github B so that both repos are in sync.

Is there any other package I can use to make these git pushes?